# Google cloud print Document Missing

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

What is document missing error in google cloud print for android?
 I am searching for solutions but not yet found.. Kindly help me..

```
  final Uri docUri = Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/downloads");
  final String docMimeType = "pdf";
  final String docTitle = "Android Interview Questions";
  btn_print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent printIntent = new Intent(PrintDialogActivity.this, PrintActivity.class);
    printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, docMimeType);
    printIntent.putExtra("title", docTitle);
    startActivity(printIntent);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Did you get answer on this?? I am also stuck on the same issue.. Although I have also placed annotations @JavascriptInterface on each and every method in the class PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface.. Still it is not working

Comment: Dear Gaurang. I dint get answer. It was my very old post.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to convert the PDF in to base64 and then send it. The best approach to do this would be to use the built in [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class that comes with Android and use the method [encodeToString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte[],%20int)) to convert your file in to a base64 string.

## How to convert file to bytes

```
File file = new File(path);
int size = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
buffer.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
buffer.close();
```

Comment: Edited the answers, I hope this make more sense now. and I hope that sending the file in Base 64 is the actual issue :) In my case that was the issue in NodeJS.